# How to put Interfaces in a library for android App

Tags: java, android, user-interface

to the point, i am working in a library for android app's, all programing part is almost finish, i am testing a idea.

the idea is put some interfaces in the librery that i am working, and this GUI can be loaded in the main app.

i try to do it but i get to error the first was i did not declare the activity in the AndroidManifest in the main app, the second one is the one a i cant solve, the autogenerated Class R don't capture the GUI that it is in the librery.

it is anyway i can do this or it is imposible.

code to see what i am trying todo

in my librery (movilsecure)

```
EmisionActivity.java (have the activity_emision.xml in the res of my librery)
```

in the Main Android App (

```
import ve.com.idyseg.movilsecure.EmisionActivity;
import ve.com.idyseg.movilsecure.MSMasterControllerTEST;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void captureEvent (View v){
        Intent intento = new Intent(this,EmisionActivity.class);
        startIntent(intento);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Review again my question i need de information, thanks to point my error's

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipses, right click the project, the click Build Path then click Add Library. Please comment if you're still stuck.

Comment: i tried this and don't load the Main App don't load the GUI (Activity) i have in the librery

Answer (score 0):

In the library's manifest, in the `<activity>` node, did you set `android:exported="true"`?

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.EmisionActivity"
    android:exported="true">
</activity>
```